# Hi, Hello, Dear in answer to client’s Hi

Tags: politeness, greetings

We’re are a small atelier on Etsy and usually get questions from clients starting with Hi, Hi Roman (they sometimes see my name before composing a question) or Hey there.

What would be the safest way of starting a reply in these cases? Currently, I use “Hello, John!” but is it ok?

We don’t need very informal relationship in conversation with customer but still want to be natural, polite and helpful.

Comment: Although you might at first glance imagine otherwise, this is primarily a cultural question that’s unrelated to the English language. If you translated this question into your first (non-English) language, then would you automatically know the “right” answer?  Why would English have a special way of handling this that works differently from however it works in your own language?

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn’t start with “Hello, dear” as your title might suggest…

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the response you're using is polite and the correct level of formality! It seems safe and okay.

Answer (score -1):

There are no rules but broadly, it's fine to respond with whatever form your respondent used… if he signs himself John, respond Dear/Hi/Hello John… if she uses Mrs Doe, respond to Mrs Doe. Where there's a doubt, fall back on the traditional standards for correspondence… which broadly give the same results, anyway. Such standards are very usefully explained in both *Webster's Dictionary* (huge desktop versions) and *Debrett's Correct Form*, among other sources.